# How to make HTTP request to Discord API?

Tags: node.js, http

I am trying to make an HTTP request to the Discord API, and I keep getting ECONNREFUSED as an error back. I am trying to access this route provided in the Discord API Documentation:

Get Global Application Commands
 GET/applications/{application.id}/commands
Fetch all of the global commands for your application. Returns an array of ApplicationCommand objects.

Using NodeJS, here is the relevant section of code:

```
const https = require('https')

const options = {
  hostname: 'https://discord.com',
  path: '/api/v8/applications/<myapplicationID>/commands',  //with my actual appID
  port: 443,
  method: 'GET',
  headers: {
    Authorization: `Bot ${process.env.TOKEN}`
  }
}
const req = https.request(options, res => {
  console.log(`statusCode: ${res.statusCode}`)
  res.on('data', d => {
    process.stdout.write(d)
  })
})

req.on('error', error => {
  console.error(error)
})

req.end()
```

I know this is a relatively simple question, but looking at the related questions didn't provide much insight, and as far as I can tell, I am adhering to the API's documentation. Any advice would be very helpful. 
Thanks,
Dylan

Comment: `ECONNREFUSED` means that you've been rejected on the TCP level. It's a networking issue, possibly your IP is blocked by a firewall.

Comment: So I tried to disable my firewall (pretty stupid maybe) and still got the error. I am really stumped on it.

Comment: There are *much* friendlier modules than the built-in `https` module for Node.js such as Axios and node-fetch.

Comment: Thank you for the advice! I ended up using node-fetch.

Answer (score 1):

So it was pretty stupid... The hostname field can't have 'https://'